# Difference between running composer scripts with run-script or without?

Tags: php, composer-php

From the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#running-scripts-manually) if I want to run a Composer script manually I need to type

```
composer run-script [--dev] [--no-dev] script-name
```

But if I write

```
composer script-name
```

The script will be executed just the same.

I was setting up scripts to run unit and integration tests, and I really see no difference between these two approaches (with or without `run-script` part).

Is there any, and what is it? Or is it just something that was needed in the earlier versions of the Composer? The documentation isn't giving much details on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `run-script` for running [standard scripts for events](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#event-names), for example you need it to run `post-update-cmd` script manually:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-update-cmd": "echo My script"
},
```

Not working:

```
$ composer post-update-cmd


  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  Command "post-update-cmd" is not defined.
```

Working:

```
$ composer run-script post-update-cmd
> echo My script
My script
```

AFAIK there is no difference between between these to approach when you want to run custom command.

---

However with `run-script` you're able to run script with the same name as composer built-in command:

```
"scripts": {
    "install": "echo My script"
},
```

Run `composer install` command:

```
$ composer install
A script named install would override a Composer command and has been skipped
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

Run `install` script:

```
$ composer run-script install
A script named install would override a Composer command and has been skipped
> echo My script
My script
```

However in such case you will get warning about conflicting script name and I would not rely on it. It does not make much sense anyway.

Comment: This makes much more sense now :) Thanks.